# Javascript: Splicing out of multiple set of arrays Functionally

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object, that contains 3 arrays of differing size with strings as some of their respective element types, but also redundant properties, that you don't want to iterate over: eg as follows:

```
let testobj = {
   prop1: ['a1','a2','a3'],
   prop2: ['a4','a5'],
   prop3: ['a7'],
   somepropthatyoudontwanttoiterate: 'hithere!'
}
```

Imperatively, if I wished to splice a specific value that could exist anywhere within any of those three arrays, I could do something like this:

```
let a = 'a7'
for (let i=0; i<testobj.prop1.length; i++){ 
    if (a == testobj.prop1[i])
        testobj.prop1.splice(i, 1)
}
for (let i=0; i<testobj.prop2.length; i++){ 
    if (a == testobj.prop2[i])
        testobj.prop2.splice(i, 1)
}
for (let i=0; i<testobj.prop3.length; i++){ 
    if (a == testobj.prop3[i])
        testobj.prop3.splice(i, 1)
}
```

This is nasty, and super error prone and not very scalable in the long run.

What would be the best **functional** way of performing this same type of thing using a higher order functions to solve this problem?  e.g. .map, .reduce, .sort, .filter?

Comment: do you have only one wanted value to splice in one array, or more in one or more than one array?

Comment: Only one, but it needs to match the name specifically in my case, and it can be in any of the arrays.

Comment: I need to edit my question, to also include a caveat unfortunately @NinaScholz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the values of the object and splice by getting the index of the wanted value of an array.

While only one element is expected in the array, you could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return early if the element is splitted.

```js
var testobj = { foo: 42, prop1: ['a1','a2','a3'], prop2: ['a4','a5'], prop3: ['a7'] },
    value = 'a7';

Object
    .values(testobj)
    .some(a => Array.isArray(a) && a.includes(value) && a.splice(a.indexOf(value), 1));

console.log(testobj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: How would you edit this if testobj also had OTHER properties on it? As in other none arrays that you didn't wish to iterate over.

Comment: That is brilliant! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

A little verbose solution, but it restricts the extra iterations if the items was found. You can see it in the logs. If the item is in the first array, it just check the first one.

```js
let testobj = {
   prop3: ['a7'],
   prop1: ['a1','a2','a3'],
   prop2: ['a4','a5']
};

Object.values(testobj).find((prop, index) => {

  console.log(`index ${index}`);
  
  const foundIndex = prop.findIndex(i => i !== 'a7');
  return foundIndex ? (prop.splice(foundIndex, 1), true) : false;
  
});

console.log(testobj);
```